# Connection issue in Ubuntu 18.04, everything looks good

Tags: networking, network-manager, tor, nmcli

I was setting up a TOR connection and all of a sudden I can't connect to anything. I've uninstalled TOR and I can't get connected to my wireless router.

The icon shows connection, and nmcli general says everything is working, but I can't get it to ACTUALLY work. I've included some of the information. I'm probably missing something so if you see what you need is missing, I will edit this.

I have restarted NMCLI, network-manager, NetworkManager, wifi radio on/off, ifup/ifdown, etc.

None of the usual things are working.

Uname - `version 5.0.0-23-generic`

lspci -

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

ifconfig:

```
enp1s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 4c:72:b9:9d:fe:f3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 12322  bytes 895314 (895.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 12322  bytes 895314 (895.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.128  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::2268:9dff:fe54:7e42  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 20:68:9d:54:7e:42  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4509  bytes 272210 (272.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 493  bytes 64787 (64.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

iwconfig:

```
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Countess"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: CC:40:D0:D3:56:84   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=64/70  Signal level=-46 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:2  Invalid misc:56   Missed beacon:0
```

lshw:

```
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 0b
       serial: 4c:72:b9:9d:fe:f3
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=half firmware=rtl8168f-2_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:17 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:d0004000-d0004fff memory:d0000000-d0003fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 01
       serial: 20:68:9d:54:7e:42
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=5.0.0-23-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.128 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:fea00000-fea7ffff memory:fea80000-fea8ffff
```

nmcli general:

```
STATE      CONNECTIVITY  WIFI-HW  WIFI     WWAN-HW  WWAN    
connected  full          enabled  enabled  enabled  enabled
```

Device info:

```
> GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp3s0 GENERAL.TYPE:          
> wifi GENERAL.HWADDR:                         20:68:9D:54:7E:42
> GENERAL.MTU:                            1500 GENERAL.STATE:           
> 100 (connected) GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Countess
> GENERAL.CON-PATH:                      
> /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1 IP4.ADDRESS[1]:    
> 192.168.0.128/24 IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.0.1 IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh =
> 192.168.0.1, mt = 600 IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.0.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 600 IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000 IP4.DNS[1]:             
> 24.229.54.212 IP4.DNS[2]:                             204.186.110.76 IP4.DNS[3]:                             204.186.0.180 IP4.DNS[4]:     
> 8.8.8.8 IP4.DNS[5]:                             8.8.4.4 IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::2268:9dff:fe54:7e42/64
> IP6.GATEWAY:                            -- IP6.ROUTE[1]:              
> dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255 IP6.ROUTE[2]:            
> dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
```

Comment: You've done a great job of listing a lot of useful information here. It may not add much to figuring this out but I was wondering what the result of route is. I believe tor adjusts your routing so it is possible your route has not been properly restored.

Comment: Did you try to reboot?

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]!  **;-)** Please [edit]  your question to provide the output of `sudo ufw status` and `sudo iptables --list`.

Comment: @Fabby The status is inactive. I've noticed that upon booting it will default to the UFW being active - and that was the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The UFW was enabled which for some reason, just blocked EVERYTHING on my system. I tried to establish a policy to allow TOR and ZeroNet, but it looks like I've botched everything up.

Comment: If someone points you in the right direction, and then you convert a comment to an answer *without asking them first if they want to answer* , **that is frowned upon here...**